# static variables not initialized in C

Tags: c, static, global, variable-assignment

In a C program I have this code in a file. It wants to use a static global variable to control verbose output. But the variable is not what I assigned, so I started to play.

```
static int _varA = 0;

void test(void)
{
    static u8 _varB = 0;
    u8 _varC = 0;
    printf("output=%d %d %d\n", _varA, _varB, _varC);
}
```

Running this function gives me `132  126  0` and I have no idea why.
What's happening here?

Static variables in other files work (global or local and I know the difference).
The name of these variables doesn't occur anywhere else in this program than what you see here.

I can't provide a minimal example because in a small project this works.
Instead I have to try finding what goes wrong in my project. Any ideas what common errors people make that could lead to this?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That includes fixing the code you post so that it is actual code, not code that was retyped with a mistake (the extra `"` in the `printf`) or somehow pasted incorrectly. And it includes all the headers and definitions needed to make the code work (`u8` is not a defined type in the posted code, and `function` causes a grammar error), and a `main` routine. Also specify which C implementation you are using, include the name of the compiler, the specific version, and the switches used to compile.

Comment: Do you include `<stdio.h>` in the test file ? Without this include file, calling `printf` would have undefined behavior.

Comment: Test whether the problem occurs when names without an underscore are used. Names starting with an underscore are reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in the ordinary and tag name spaces, per C 2018 7.1.3 1. Another possibility is you are using an environment that does not conform to the C standard, such as a specialized embedded system that does not automatically initialize all data with static storage duration. Test whether the problem occurs when `= 0` is changed to `= 1`.

Comment: You are right, that example is a mess. That came because I edited my original identifiers to something more generic for the example. I changed my code to what you see now, that's a copy of my code and still doesn't work. In a separate new project things work fine as it's also the case for other code files.

Comment: Re “I can't provide a minimal example because in a small project this works”: That is a sign something in your program is corrupting memory. Call `test` at the beginning of your program and at other times, to narrow down where the corruption occurs. If your debugging facilities support it, put watchpoints on the variables. In any case, if you cannot present it as a [mre], it is not a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `static` variables are most definitely initialized to 0 (if no initial value is provided), or whatever initial value is specified in the code.  The code you've shown will definitely output `0 0 0`.  As others have said, the culprit is elsewhere in your program.

Comment: You don't really want to know the _"common errors people make"_.  You want to know what error _you_ have made, and it probably is not that common.  The code fragment you have provided certainly does not exhibit the error - it is clearly elsewhere in code not presented. Overrunning an adjacent buffer is one possibility.

Comment: According to what Eric says I am now focusing on other code that corrupts memory. Sounds plausible, as well as the suggestions to examine that. I am afraid if the error is not in this code, which seems to be the case after all, this question becomes useless and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted, your question cannot be answered precisely: there are multiple problems you should fix to make the code cleaner and allow for proper investigation:

- post a complete source code with include files and a `main` function that exhibits the problem.
- post the definitions of all types and macros used in the example: `u8` is probably a typedef for `unsigned char` or a macro, but as posted no one can tell for sure. It is also unclear what `function` expands to.
- avoid reserved names starting with an `_`. Use plain names for both global, static and local variables.
- try with and without initializers for global variables (and `static` local one). Also try with non zero initializers.
- describe your target platform and toolchain.  Many embedded development suites are notoriously inadequate in terms of standard conformity. Tagging the question with appropriate tags (target system and toolchain) would attract attention from developers knowledgeable with the specific shortcomings.

As commented by @EricPotstpischil, the most likely explanation for your problem is code run before calling the `test()` function causes memory corruption, overwriting part of the data segment, causing global variables to receive a value different from their initial or expected value. Here are ideas to investigate this problem:

- set watchpoints on the static or global variable that gets changed and let the debugger flag when the change occurs. Some debuggers are able to do this. If you are lucky, this is the easiest and quickest way.
- sprinkle calls to a test function with extra arguments such as `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, and produce output if the global variable changes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int varA = 0;

int test(const char *file, int line) {
    static u8 varB = 0;
    
    if (varA || varB) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: problem detected: varA=%d, varB=%d\n",
               file, line, varA, varB);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can add `#define TEST()  test(__FILE__, __LINE__)` in an include file and sprinkle the source code with calls to `TEST()`

Comment: *You can add #define `TEST()  test(__FILE__, __LINE__)` in an include file ...* I've found that `__func__` adds a lot of very useful context to log utilities like that.  You don't have to find the exact line in the source code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: of course `__func__` can be passed too for more informative messages. I personally use just filename:lineno because, running from my [editor](https://github.com/qemacs/qemacs) shell buffer, `^X^N` points me directly to the offending code.

Comment: IME, with the additional information from `__func__` there's often no need to go to the source code to ascertain what's going on, making it a significant time-saver.